# IPhone iPod app: how do you get out of the iTunes store?

Tags: iphone, itunes, ios, applications, ipod

A question about the built-in iPod app on iPhone. Once you get into the iTunes mode (e.g. after clicking "get more episodes" on a podcast view) it seems you are stuck forever wandering the endless isles of the iTunes store.

When you first open the iPod app, going to "podcasts" shows the podcasts that are downloaded to your phone. But once you've gone into "iTunes mode", clicking "podcasts" now reveals all the podcasts available on iTunes.

How do you get back to the original mode? The only way I've found is exiting the iPod app and opening it again. Is that really the way it's designed (presumably "by Apple in California")?

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you refer to as "iTunes mode" is actually a separate application called iTunes. The only way to get back is to relaunch the iPod app. If you have a multitasking-capable device, you can double tap on the home button and the iPod app will be there as it was the most recently used app.

Comment: Doh! I always assumed that that thing when it looks like it's loading another app was just for show. It all makes sense now. Thanks!